# JAVA: trouble finding which element of array to use in a function?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In my Undead class I have a method written which allows an undead character to sacrifice itself and split its remaining health between the two remaining team mates (the total number of players in the array of chars is always 3).

My function for this is

```
public void sacrifice(Character other1, Character other2){
    int healthgiven = health/2; 
    health -= health;
    other1.health += healthgiven; 
    other2.health += healthgiven;
    System.out.println(name + " has sacrified himself for the team. 
    His health has been distributed among the two remaining allies. ");
}
```

This works as far as I know, but it becomes a problem when I have to use it in the main. I somehow have to figure out which elements of the list are the two other characters (who can be Undead as well). Basically when I end up calling undeadchar.sacrifice(other1, other2), I need to find the two characters that are not undeadchar. Sorry if it's confusing I will rewrite this if necessary.

Comment: Are your characters in an array or a list? (You use both words.)

Comment: You can't do `undeadchar.sacrifice(other1, other2)` from main() method since sacrifice is not a static method.

Comment: Sorry! My characters are located in ArrayList<Character> of size 3 (it's always 3). And I'm trying to find out how determine which characters from that list are not calling the sacrifice function (so I can use them as parameters) if that makes sense.

Comment: I can do it, it works so far, the only problem I'm having is what I mentioned in the question. I should have given more code probably but I really just need a concept on how I could extract those two characters.

Comment: Need only code and little explanation to get you a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should place a check before calling the method `sacrifice`.
Assuming that you have `getHealth()` function in your `Player` and once the player sacrifices health the health of player is `0` then,

```
List<Player> PlayersList = new ArrayList<Player>();
Player sacrificingPlayer = ... //Your logic to find sacrificing player
List<Player> healthyPlayers = GetHealthyPlayer(PlayersList );
sacrificingPlayer.sacrifice(healthyPlayers.get(0), healthyPlayers.get(1));
```

and function `GetHealthyPlayer();`

```
public List<Player> GetHealthyPlayer(List<Player> PlayersList )
{
  List<Player> Players = new ArrayList<Player>();
  int PlayerCount = 0;
  for (Player pl: PlayersList )
  {
      if(pl.getHealth() > 0)
      { 
         Players.add(pl);
         PlayerCount++;
         if(PlayerCount == 2) //Since we need only two healthy player
             break;
       }
  }
  if(PlayerCount != 2) 
      throw Exception("Two healthy players not found "); //Or you Can return null and check
  return Players;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8:

```
List<Character> charList = ... 
Character sacrificeChar = ...
List<Character> notSacrificeList = charList.stream()
                                        .filter(x -> !x.equals(sacrificeChar))
                                        .map(Character::new)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Hey, downvoter, care to detail why you downvoted my answer? It's perfectly valid, you know ...

Comment: No it's not, the other two characters can be undead too.

Comment: I have updated my answer, now he will get the other 2 chars :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like:

```
ArrayList<Character> chars = ...; // all of them
Character sacrificingChar = ...; // the one that will sacrifice himself
```

Then you can do:

```
List<Character> others = new ArrayList<>(chars);
others.remove(sacrificingChar);
sacrificingChar.sacrifice(others.get(0), others.get(1));
```

Comment: Hmmm this seems to work so far. The only problem I can see is that the list of characters if used later on in the code. Do I have to put the sacrificing Character back in?

Comment: @Howcan No, it creates a copy of the original list. You can throw the `others` list away afterwards. It doesn't change the contents of your main character list.